# Parsing Java Dates

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to parse dates. From what I understand from the javadocs this should work. I thing this should work becuase on the JavaDoc is said that `Date.parse()` is deprecated and should be replaced with `DateFormat.parse()`.

```
 DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().parse(Date().toString())
```

but it does not.

`Date().toString()` returns a `String` like

```
Sun Jun 18 10:09:50 CDT 2017
```

When I try to parse this string, a `ParseException` is thrown

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Jun 18 10:09:50 CDT 2017"
```

Also I am using Kotlin so `Date()` is the same thing as `new Date()`

Comment: sure @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: What do you mean by `What does it does not mean?`

Comment: I cannot more strongly advise against using the legacy `java.util.Date` if you can possibly avoid it.  You should instead look in the `java.time` package and find the class that is most appropriate for your use case.

Comment: @JoeC Thanks a lot, this has fixed my problem. I remember finding these classes a while back but forgot about them.

Comment: *From what I understand from the javadocs this should work*: could you explain your train of thought? Does the javadoc of DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance() say that it returns a DateFormat able to parse what Date.toString() generates?

Answer (score 0):

Using the new `java.time` classes I was able to solve the problem.

The current date you can get with `LocalDateTime.now()` and the date string can be parsed with `LocalDateTime.parse()`